# matplotlib animation removing lines during update

Tags: python, pandas, animation, matplotlib

I've created a map and I am reading in a CSV of latitude and longitude coordinates into a Pandas DataFrame. I've been successful in plotting multiple great arcs using a 'for' loop after reading in the DataFrame.

A new great arc is drawn when a new set of coordinates is ADDED to the CSV.

However, I can't figure out how to REMOVE a great arc once the coordinates have been removed. The line just stays on the map.

How do I remove all the old lines and re-draw the lines everytime the CSV is updated? I only want to see the lines currently contained within the CS.

The CSV contains the following:

```
sourcelon   sourcelat   destlon    destlat
50.44        30.51      -80.84      35.22
52.52        13.4       -80.84      35.22
43.18       -22.97      -80.84      35.22
44.1        -15.97      -80.84      35.22
55.44        30.51      -80.84      35.22
```

The minimal code is below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation


# setup mercator map projection.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(27, 20))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='r', linewidth=1.0)


def animate(i):

    df = pd.read_csv('c:/python/scripts/test2.csv', sep='\s*,\s*',header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python'); df 


    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')



ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Using blitting:

When using blitting the lines are automatically removed.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation


# setup mercator map projection.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)

def get_data():
    a = (np.random.rand(4,2)-0.5)*300
    b = (np.random.rand(4,2)-0.5)*150
    df= pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1),
                     columns=['sourcelon','destlon','sourcelat','destlat'])
    return df

def animate(i):
    df = get_data()
    lines = []
    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')
        lines.append(line)
    return lines

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Without blitting:

If blitting is not desired, one may remove the lines manually.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation


# setup mercator map projection.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines(color='grey', linewidth=1.0)

def get_data():
    a = (np.random.rand(4,2)-0.5)*300
    b = (np.random.rand(4,2)-0.5)*150
    df= pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1),
                     columns=['sourcelon','destlon','sourcelat','destlat'])
    return df

lines = []

def animate(i):
    df = get_data()
    for line in lines:
        line.remove()
        del line
    lines[:] = []
    for x,y,z,w in zip(df['sourcelon'], df['sourcelat'], df['destlon'], df['destlat']):
        line, = m.drawgreatcircle(x,y,z,w,color='r')
        lines.append(line)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That did it. Consequently I found something else....is there a way to prevent longitudinal wrapping of plots?

Comment: Is there any way to recale/autoscale the axes *with* blitting? Not looking for detailes, - yes,no, easy, hard is fine.

Comment: @wwii In principle you can blit anything you want, but you would need to implement it yourself (outside of `FuncAnimation`). Scaling the axes and subsequently drawing the axes ticks is rather expensive, so it might happen that you don't gain much at the end when blitting an autoscaled axes. So in total, I'd say, "possible, intermediately complex" as short answer here. ;-)